# error namespace cannot directly contain fields or methods

Tags: c#, namespaces

[image]

Please help me on this error....I get when trying to run the code above in the link

Comment: Dont paste external links. Please use snippet

Comment: @Erin I would read up on how to code C# basics you cannot create an entry point in your code this way.. is this a Console App..? you're Main should look like this `static void Main(string[] args)` also should be inside a Class not directly under `namespace{ }` here some tutorials you can read http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/main-method/

Comment: Surround everything by either `static class Program { ... }` or `public class Program { ... }` depending on your needs.

Comment: Simply move `static void Main() {}` into a class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods" in Net.Reflector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175781/a-namespace-cannot-directly-contain-members-such-as-fields-or-methods-in-net-r)

Comment: Main Function Needs to be moved in a class before execution as it can not be directly used in a namespace as suggested by @mjwills and Sebastian .

Answer (score 3):

**A namespace is a collection of classes.**

And since static void is a method, it throws an error. So you need to move it like this:

```
namespace EmployeeProgram
{
  public class employee
   {
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {}
   }
}
```