# How to use static method to initialize ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder object and reset it c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, static, singleton

My old code is like :

```
public static async Task SendMessageToServiceBus(string topicName, string message, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder sbc = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStringSettingName"));
        sbc.EntityPath = topicName;

        TopicClient tc = new TopicClient(sbc);

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message.ToString());

        await tc.SendAsync(new Message(bytes));

        log.LogInformation($"Successfully published a message to {topicName}");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Error: " + exception.ToString());
    }
}
```

Instead if creating `ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder sbc` object
every time I want to use it as a static and want to reset it on every
call.

```
public static class testData
{
    public static ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder sbc = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStringSettingName"));

    [FunctionName("test")]
    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "sub", Connection = "ConnectionStringSettingName")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
    {
        await SendMessageToServiceBus("topicname", mySbMsg, log);
```

And inside method `SendMessageToServiceBus` reset `sbc` like:

```
testData.sbc.Clear();
```

But this is not working for me getting error :

> A namespace cannot directly contain member or field

Comment: Which line is the error on? It looks like it's possibly not on one of the lines you've shown.

Comment: Is it possible that you could edit your post to separate your code examples from your text.

Comment: ok let me update question again

Comment: The error say namespace. I don't the code outside of a class here your sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175781/a-namespace-cannot-directly-contain-members-such-as-fields-or-methods-in-net-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods" in Net.Reflector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175781/a-namespace-cannot-directly-contain-members-such-as-fields-or-methods-in-net-r)